# Single reducer or multiple reducers for a large state?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

With Redux, would it be more logical to keep an extremely large (more than 4000 values) state with a single reducer or to divide the state into multiple parts and keep them in reducers?

Comment: You don't _"keep"_ things in reducers. However, if you're deciding between complex reducer and multiple elementary ones, I'd chose the latter as [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) suggests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ***size*** of the state shouldn't be the deciding factor, but rather it is the ***complexity***, e.g. the structure, of the state that should be. A single reducer owning a slice of state with 4000 properties or array elements is completely fine, but if the 4000 values form an object with deeply nested properties, well then this makes for a case for splitting the nested properties out into their own sub-state, e.g. reducers, which are then combined together to form the reducer tree, e.g. the state tree.

In other words:

If the state is a flat structure of 4000 related properties/values, then a single reducer is fine.

```js
const initialState = {};

const myState = createSlice({
  name: "myState",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    updateMyState: (state, action) => {
      const { key, value } = action.payload;
      state[key] = value;
    },
  },
});
```

If the state shape is more complex, split the state up so each slice of state is responsible for a single non-nested "chunk" of it.

Example:

```js
const initialState = {};

const foo = createSlice({
  name: "foo",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    updateFoo: (state, action) => {
      const { key, value } = action.payload;
      state[key] = value;
    },
  },
});
```

```js
const initialState = {
  someArray: [],
};

const foo = createSlice({
  name: "bar",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    updateBar: (state, action) => {
      state.someArray.push(action.payload);
    },
  },
});
```

```js
const initialState = {
  isBuzz: false,
};

const bizz = createSlice({
  name: "bizz",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    updateBizzBuzz: (state, action) => {
      state.isBuzz = action.payload === "buzz";
    },
  },
});
```

```js
const foobar = combineReducers({
  foo: foo.reducer,
  bar: bar.reducer,
});
```

```js
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  foobar,
  buzz: buzz.reducer
});
```

```js
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
});
```

You can see here how the reducers form a state tree:

```
state
+--foobar
|  +--foo
|  +--bar
|     +--someArray
+--buzz
   +--isBuzz
```

The general suggestion or "rule of thumb" is that each state slice/reducer should only be responsible for a "flat" or *very* shallow group of related values.